# click button one time per one sec until

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a button click until some condition. I think that set timeout is needed to use ? At now the button clicks one time on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

attBtn.trigger('click'); 

});
```

But how to trigger it every second until some condition `if` ?

Comment: Use `setInterval()`, ***however*** this is a *very* odd thing to be doing. For what reason do you need this?

Comment: Auto fight mode in my website. It's like first time you click attack button then it auto clicks rest of the time till user HP is zero. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In which case use the interval to call a defined function. Faking button click events is not a good idea.

Comment: setTimeout(function() { if(contiion here) { attBtn.trigger('click'); }}, 1000); 
Not sure if this is a good solution tho.... you gotta be sure that your condition to stop the trigger works. Also please check this link oot to clear the timeout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: please, search it first on stackoverflow. there's many many of similar questions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why it's not good idea ? Button let's say clicked 10 times then the function is triggered. :)

Comment: It's better to call a function ? Maybe delete the button and set interval for function calling ? :)

Comment: It's a bad idea because browsers know which events are from genuine user interaction and which are faked through code. If you start raising events programmatically at too high a rate the browser's security may block/ignore the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Auto fight mode in my website. It's like first time you click attack button then it auto clicks rest of the time till user HP is zero.

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run a function where the *HP* is decreased each second (1000 ms) until it reaches 0... Where the use of `clearInterval()` stops the process.

Here is an example:

```js
var FightInterval;
$("#fight").on("click",function(){
  FightInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var HP = $("#life").text();
    if(HP>0){
      $("#life").text(HP-1);
    }else{
      clearInterval(FightInterval);
    }
  },1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ennemy HP : <span id="life">10</span><br>
<br>
<button id="fight">Fight</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not `setTimeout()` but `setInterval()`.
You need to contain it inside a variable
Inside `setInterval()` callback, do the check to stop the loop

```
var loop
var stop
loop = setInterval(function() {
    // Do you stuff

    if(stop) { clearInterval(loop) }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Watch the capitals at the line begin... Particularly on `var` and `if`... That answer is close to a correct solution (in my opinion), but needs to be edited ;)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry...typing on the phone makes them capital letter

Comment: I cant edit my answer . Theres no edit button on my answer, but there are on other peoples answers. Whats goin on?

Comment: oh i cant approve edits from my phone, thanks for the edit Martijn Vissers

Answer (score 0):

```
if(whatever conditions you want)
{
    setTimeout(yourClickFunction, 1000)
}
```

Under what conditions do you want it to stop?